# How to show a black background with portion of a view in SwiftUI on DragGesture?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm attempting to implement a swipe functionality left/right where I want the user to swipe left/right between views (in this example the circle and rectangle). While I have the left/right detecting and switching between views working I am not sure how to implement it so that as a user drags for example left, the user slowly sees the next view until it snaps into place.

Here's what it currently looks like and the code.

```swift
struct Swipe: View {
    @State private var xOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var showCircle: Bool = false
    @State private var showRectangle: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Current xOffset: \(xOffset)")
            ZStack {
                if showCircle {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                }
                
                if showRectangle {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .offset(x: xOffset)
                }
            }
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged {
                        value in
                        withAnimation(Animation.spring()) {
                            xOffset = value.translation.width
                        }
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        if value.predictedEndLocation.x < -100 || value.predictedEndLocation.x > 100 {
                            showCircle.toggle()
                            showRectangle.toggle()
                        }
                        xOffset = 0.0
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

But what I want is the transition during the `DragGesture`. I've tried to draw it as best as I can where that black color is the background while it's transitioning to the next view. [image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your animation like paging, use [TabView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview):

```
TabView(selection: $selectedPage) {
    ForEach(pageList, id: \.self) { page in
        if page == .circle {
            CircleView()
        } else { 
            RectangleView()
        }
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

Remember if pageList's type is `Array<T>` then selectedPage's type must be `T`

Comment: To think that there was something so simple, thank you so much! Truly you don't know what you don't know hah. Any advice on finding things like these in the future?

Comment: practice more I guess =))

Comment: hah, got it. Thank you :]